# In a Pine script, I want to use the RSI Divergence indicator in the strategy in a different TIMEFRAME

Tags: pine-script

In a Pine script, I want to use the RSI Divergence indicator in the strategy in a different timeframe.

Can you show the missing codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the request.security function :

```
// Your function ((here rsi)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 7)

// This sends the `rsi` calculation for execution in the context of the chart symbol at a "240" (4 hours) timeframe.
   
rsi240 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", rsi)
```